# Assigning to Rvalue error in Polymer

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, polymer

im trying to make Polymer and Python communicate. But I keep getting an error about "rvalue". Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    <paper-input label="Geef je naam" value="{{naam}}"></paper-input>
     <paper-input label="telefoon nummer" value="{{telnr}}"></paper-input>
     <paper-button on-tap="contactToevoegen">Voeg contact toe</paper-button>
     {{naam}}
     {{telnr}}
     <iron-ajax
      id="ajax-contact-toevoegen"
      method="POST"
      url="/cgi-bin/contact-toevoegen.py"
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="contactToevoegen_ResponseHandler">
      </iron-ajax>
     </template>
     <script>
      Polymer({
      is: "contact-form",
      contactToevoegen: function() {
          this.$.ajax-contact-toevoegen.contentType="application/json";
          this.$.ajax-contact-toevoegen.body={naam: this.naam, telnr:                                         
      this.telnr};
     this.$.ajax-contact-toevoegen.generateRequest();
     console.log(
     "Contact: "
     + this.naam
     + ", "
     + this.telnr);
     }
      });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is javascript bad syntax.

```
this.$.ajax-contact..
```

You can't point to attribute of some object with `-` . If you have `-` in your ID you have to call it like:

```
this.$["ajax-contact-toevoegen"]
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I got it to work! 
Nice to see someone reply.

Comment: if it solved your problem, can you please accept my answer? it is just bettter for all people in the future

Comment: Oh yes of course. This is the first time I asked something on Stackoverflow.